# código número perfecto rstudio

Tags: r, rstudio

Me piden construir un código que pidiendo un número al usuario diga si es perfecto o no. Este es el código que he usado pero me manda error desde que genero el rango del contador

```
perfect=function(n){
} 
s=0

for (i in 1:n){
} if (n%%i=0)
  (s+=i)

return(s=n)
```

Answer (score 0):

Empecemos por definir un ["número perfecto"](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%C3%BAmero_perfecto#:%7E:text=Un%20n%C3%BAmero%20perfecto%20es%20un,son%2028%2C%20496%20y%208128.) como aquel entero positivo que es igual a la suma de sus divisores (excepto el mismo), por ejemplo el 6 = 1 + 2 + 3, por lo cual, la idea sería, recorrer de 1 a n-1, o mucho mejor a n/2

```
is.perfect <- function(n) {
  
  suma <- 0
  for (i in 1:ceiling(n/2)) {
    if (n %% i == 0)
      suma <- suma + i
  }
  suma == n
}

is.perfect(6)
is.perfect(28)
is.perfect(2)
```